# Why does this formula produce $p_{2}$ probabilities for Mahalanobis distances?

Tags: p-value, amos, mahalanobis

At [the IBM website](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-are-probabilities-calculated-mahalanobis-distances-amos) it is written that

> The p1 probabilities are standard probabilities of an observation from
>   a multivariate normal distribution being that far or further from the
>   centroid, which are based on a cumulative central chi-squared
>   distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the number of observed
>   variables.

and

> The p2 probabilities are probabilities of the ordered values of N
>   distances being as far or further away from the centroid.

The [AMOS development website](http://amosdevelopment.com/webhelp/discussionofexample1.htm) adds that

> Small numbers in the p1 column are to be expected. Small numbers in
>   the p2 column, on the other hand, indicate observations that are
>   improbably far from the centroid under the hypothesis of normality.

The formula for $p_{2}$, along with a worked example is given at [another part of the same website](http://amosdevelopment.com/support/faq/mahalanobis-p2.html). The page discusses “Calculating p2 for the case with the k-th largest d2”, stating that

In general, for the case that is k-th furthest from the centroid (meaning that there are $k-1$ cases further from the centroid), $p_{2}$ is calculated by first evaluating $p_{1}$ for that case and then calculating
$p_{2} = 1 \\
- _{N}C_{N-0}(1-p_{1})^{N}(p_{1})^{0} \\
- _{N}C_{N-1}(1-p_{1})^{N-1}(p_{1})^{1} \\
- _{N}C_{N-2}(1-p_{1})^{N-2}(p_{1})^{2} \\
    ...\\
- _{N}C_{N-k+1}(1-p_{1})^{N-k+1}(p_{1})^{k-1} \\
$

where N is the number of cases.

I understand how to convert d-squared values into $p_{1}$ values. With some R code (below) I can reproduce the $p_{2}$ values given in the worked example at the aforementioned webpage. I also understand the point of the $p_{2}$ values is to provide the probability the case from our dataset with this rank (highest d-squared, second-highest d-squared, etc) would be that far or further from the centroid, assuming multivariate normality. So if the highest d-squared values come along with very low $p_{2}$ values, that suggests a violation of multivariate normality.

But I don’t really understand why the formula should give these probabilities. What is the intuition behind it?

```
amos_p1 <- c(.0046132,.0085718,.0390278,.0437704,.0475222)

N = 73;

amos_p2 <- numeric(length(amos_p1))


for (i in 1:length(amos_p1))
  { 
  k <- i;
  p1_value <- amos_p1[i];

  start_value <- 1;

  while (k >= 1)
    {
      start_value = start_value - choose(N,N-k+1) * (1-p1_value)^(N-k+1) * (p1_value)^(k-1)
      k <- k-1;
    }

  amos_p2[i] <- start_value;

  } 

print(amos_p2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), so they follow standard distributional results for those types of statistics.  In the case where you have random vectors $\mathbf{X}_1, ..., \mathbf{X}_n \sim \text{IID N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ from the multivariate normal distribution with dimension $m$, you get the squared [Mahalanobis distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance):

$$D_i \equiv D^2(\mathbf{X}_i) 
= (\mathbf{X}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{X}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu}).$$

It can be shown that $D_i \sim \text{ChiSq}(m)$, so if we let $d_i = D^2(\mathbf{x}_i)$ denote the corresponding observed value, then the "$p_1$" probabilities for these observed distances are:

$$\begin{aligned}
p_{1}(d_i) 
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(D_i \geqslant d_i) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{d_i}^\infty \text{ChiSq}(r|m) \ dr \\[6pt]
&= 1 - F_\text{ChiSq}(d_i|m). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Now, letting $D_{(1)},...,D_{(n)}$ be the order statistics for the distance values (i.e., sorted into increasing order) we can use a [standard probability result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) for the distribution of order statistics for absolutely continuous random variables, to get the "$p_2$" probabilities for the observed ordered-distances, which are:$^\dagger$

$$\begin{aligned}
p_{2}(d_{(i)}) 
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(D_{(i)} \geqslant d_{(i)}) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} {n \choose j} (1 - p_{1}(d_i))^{j} \cdot p_{1}(d_i)^{n-j}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

This appears to be the formula you are inquiring about.  It is derived from the probability rule for order statistics of absolutely continuous random variables.

---

$^\dagger$ Note also that the corresponding marginal densities of the ordered-squared-distances are:

$$\begin{aligned}
f_{D_{(i)}}(d_{(i)}) 
&= \frac{n!}{(i-1)! (n-i)!} \cdot F_D(d_{(i)})^{i-1} \cdot (1-F_D(d_{(i)}))^{n-i} \cdot f_d(d_{(i)}) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n!}{(i-1)! (n-i)!} \cdot (1 - p_{1}(d_i))^{i-1} \cdot p_{1}(d_i)^{n-i} \cdot \text{ChiSq}(d_{(i)}|m). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I was trying to explain it and was obtaining the results with binomial experiments. Given K samples from a multivariate Gaussian, from near to far from the mean: $n_{1}$, ... ,$n_{k}$. p2($n_{k}$) is obtained with a binomial~B(K,p) with p=dnorm($n_{k}$,mu,sigma), and is the probability of having one or more of K elements farther from the mean than $n_{k}$. The next p2($n_{k-1}$) is obtained with binomial~B(K,p) with p=dnorm($n_{k-1}$,mu,sigma), and is the probability of having two or more of K elements farther from the mean than $n_{k-1}$.

Comment: That is a good approach to explaining it, and indeed, that is the general method through which the formulae for the distributions of order statistics are derived.